# Java EJB find by Foreign key

Tags: java, ejb

I've watched a tutorial about EJB and tried to use it in my own Project.
If I try to call the `find()` function and search by the row ID I get my results. But now I have the Problem that I just have the foreign key to search.
If I use the `find()` and passing the foreign key as Parameter I get an exception. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`
Now I'd like to know if ist even possible to use the `find()` function without the Primary key or should I create a DAO with my `SQL-Query` inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than building a DAO, your project is already probably taking advantage of the JPA with an Entity Manager, which is itself a DAO already.

If this is the case, I would build a specific named query, by putting a named query on top of your entity, or in a convenient utility class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(
    name="findMyEntityWithFK",
    queryString="SELECT e FROM EntityTable e WHERE e.myForeignKey = :myForeignKey")
```

and then you can simply:

```
Query queryByFK = em.createNamedQuery("findMyEntityWithFK");
queryByFK.setParameter("myForeignKey", "xyz");
Collection entities = queryByFK.getResultList();
```